# [Thingsboard]: How to access defined server attributes in rule chain to be used in script?

Tags: thingsboard

Rule Chain

**Description**

I would like to use a server attribute called "SO2_H_SP" already defined in the device [Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBufi.png)

to be used in a rule chain script node to check a condition to compare if setpoint has been reached or no in comparison to a telemetry value called "SO2". [Fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62z7g.png)

The setpoint value "SO2_H_SP" is variable and can be changed by user in UI. [Fig 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko5uc.png)

I've tried originator nodes but always get NULL values.

Please help ..

Comment: You should use the "originator attributes" node, mark debug mode on to see what is happening, make sure that you have written "SO2_H_SP" correctly in the server attributes.